# Does either/both of the properties $E[M]=mp$ and $M\stackrel{a.s.}{\to}mp$ imply that $E\left[\frac{1}{M}\right]=\frac{1}{mp}$?

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, uniform-convergence, expected-value

Let $X_1,\dots,X_m$ be a set of $m$ i.i.d observations. Define $$
M = \sum_{i=1}^m 1_{X_i \in [a,b]}.
$$
where $1_{X_i \in [a,b]}$ is the indicator function for the observation $X_i$ falling in the interval $[a,b]$. Define $p$ to be the probability of an observation falling the interval $[a,b]$.
$$
p = P(X_i \in [a,b]) = E[1_{X_i \in [a,b]}].
$$

Note that $E[M] = mp$, and $M \stackrel{a.s.}{\to}mp$.

Since we have these properties for $M$, I want to know can we say
$$
\begin{align}
E\bigg[\frac{1}{M}\bigg] = \frac{1}{mp}, \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad E\bigg[\frac{1}{M^2}\bigg] = \frac{1}{(mp)^2}.
\end{align}
$$

If this is not valid, does it hold that
$$
\begin{align}
E\bigg[\frac{1}{M}\bigg] \to \frac{1}{mp}, \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad E\bigg[\frac{1}{M^2}\bigg] \to \frac{1}{(mp)^2},
\end{align}
$$
in some appropriate mode of convergence as $m \to \infty$?

Comment: For every $m$, $\mathbb{P}(M=0)$ is positive, so $1/M$ is equal to $\infty$ with positive probability, therefore $\mathbb{E}(1/M) = \infty$ for all $m$.

Comment: No, if $X$ is normal then $1/X$ would be inverse normal.  You're defining $M$ to be the number of $X_i$ that are in the interval $(a,b)$.  $M$ is a binomial distribution with sample size $m$ and parameter $p = \mathbb{P}(X \in (a,b))$.  If $p< 1$ then it's always a small but positive probability for $M$ to equal $0$.

Comment: Ok, I see now thanks. I actually simplified this question somewhat for clarity, it seems that it would have been better to post the actual question as this might not be an issue then. I will post the actual question later when I get some time.

Comment: @Adam I just asked a somewhat related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922352/is-e-bigg-frac11-x-in-a-b-fx-bigg-finite). The 'real' question I'm interested in is essentially a combination of the question on this page and the new question.

Comment: @Adam Here is my actual [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922427/question-on-expectation-found-in-a-proof-it-seems-there-is-a-mistake)