# Is $E\bigg[\dfrac{1}{1_{X \in [a,b]}} f(X)\bigg]$ finite?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable and let $f(X)$ be some arbitrary function of $X$. If needed, we can assume $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$.

Let $1_{X \in [a,b]}$ be the indicator function for $X$ falling in the interval $[a,b]$.

I want to know is the following expectation finite?

$$
E\bigg[\frac{1}{1_{X \in [a,b]}} f(X)\bigg].
$$

Comment: Hi there, what happens when $X \not \in [a,b]$ ?

Comment: It is equal to zero outside the interval.

Comment: so your expression is essentially $1_{X \in [a,b]} f(X)$ , isn't it ?

Comment: I don't know where you got that from?

Comment: Let $Y$ be your term. It's equal to $ f(X) $ when $X \in [a,b]$ , $0$ when $X \not \in [a,b]$ , so $Y$ is just $f(X)$ multiplied by the indicator $1_{ X \in [a,b]}$

Comment: Or there are any additional rules for your expression?

Comment: Cant divide by zero!

Comment: But he just told me they're equal to "zero out the interval"

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen $1_{X \in [a,b]}$ is a random variable not a constant so we can't just pull it out of the expectation unless I'm missing something. And $1_{X \in [a,b]}f(X)$ is not the term I asked about in any case, I asked about $1/1_{X \in [a,b]} f(X)$.

Comment: I didn't pull it out of any expectation. I just explain to you what your random variable $$\dfrac{1}{1_{X \in [a,b] } f(X)$$ means by just what you have told me.

Comment: If you expect more from that expression, you should have written it out. By all means, I think it's not hard to look into my profile to see that I'm not kind of undergraduate student who does not know what is a random variable, right?

Comment: $1/1_{X \in [a,b]}$ is infinity not zero when $X$ is not in $[a,b]$ so it looks like this expectation can't be defined.