# Question on expectation found in a proof - it seems there is a mistake?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

I have been trying to understand a lemma in a paper and now I think there might be a mistake in it. I would like to confirm this to be sure I have not misunderstood something. I don't want to link the paper out of respect for the authors but I've attached an image of the lemma below. Note that $S$ in the lemma represents a compact set and the $X_i$ are i.i.d random variables. While it says $h$ is an arbitrary function, a common example of $h$ used in practise is $h(x) = e^{-x^2}$.

Specifically, I think there may be a mistake in the lemma regarding $E[\frac{1}{N^k} |A_n|]$. I think this quantity is infinite so the result given for it is meaningless. If we simplify it right down, by setting $n=1$ and $k = 1$, we have
$$
E\bigg[\frac{1}{N} |A_1|\bigg] = E\bigg[\frac{1}{1(X \in S)} |h(X)| \bigg],
$$
and the expectation can't exist because of the indicator function in the denominator which will result in a division by zero. Am I correct that there is a mistake in this lemma for this reason or have I overlooked something?

[image]

Note the paper also says that for their application $h$ is a kernel function, e.g. $h(x) = e^{-x^2}$ as mentioned above, and for this reason the condition $E[\frac{1}{N^k}|An|]^2 < \infty$ is trivially satisfied.

Comment: I suppose your $X_i$ are random variables?  What do we know about their distribution? Why isn't $d$ decorated with an $i$?

Comment: The $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables so the same $d$ holds for all of them.

Comment: The fact that we have double subscript variables $X_{ik}$ in the function $h$ is a bit confusing and not relevant to this question. For the purposes of my question it is fine to assume $k = 1$ and thus we just have $A_n = \sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i)$.

Comment: It is possible for $N$ to equal $0$, but the hypothesis of the theorem says "if $E(N^{-k} |A_n|) < \infty$, then ..."  So the statement of the theorem can still be correct.  Since $|A_n|$ is nonzero (I'm assuming), assuming the expectation is finite is the same as assuming that $N>0$

Comment: But $N$ is explicitly defined as a sum of indicator functions dependent on $X_i$ so how can they make an assumption about it?

Comment: It looks like if there is some division by zero issue then it is present on both sides so it is consistent albeit useless.